# OIDC to SAML options?

Tags: openid, openid-connect, saml, saml-2.0

I have two services, and am looking to allow users to login to one service from the other. However, the service that makes the most sense as IdP only allows OIDC, while my other service (acting as SP here) only accepts SAML. I don’t own either service, so I can’t add support for SAML/OIDC to these services. We also don’t have any auto provisioning via SAML or anything like that, so it’s not a concern.

My current thought to use some sort of intermediary. Whether some sort of IdP solution like Ping or OneLogin can do this remains to be seen, but a custom web server could.

1. Client requests access to SP
2. SP redirects to an intermediary via Appropriate URL in SAML config
3. SAML intermediary redirects user to IdP OIDC login
4. User logs in IdP, intermediary uses code to retrieve token and validate user login
5. Intermediary generates SAML assertion based on successful OIDC authentication and allows user to login to SP

I’ve convinced myself this will work, but SHOULD it? Are there better alternatives? Aside from telling my users it probably doesn’t make sense to do this, is there another way?

What makes this objectively OK or not OK?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally one likes to avoid complexity by adding additional moving pieces anywhere, especially in something as sensitive as authentication.  But the reality of most software development is that you have to integrate various pre-existing components into new solutions, and that often includes incorporating existing identity providers.  (Migrating large numbers of identities and credentials introduces its own complexity and risk!)  So you definitely see these "authentication adapter" patterns in real-world systems.  And there exist well-tested tools for it so you don't have to take the risk of rolling your own.

One commonly used tool is [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org) (or the commercially-supported version, RedHat SSO).   Keycloak allows you to use external [OIDC IdPs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_identity_broker_oidc) and have users connect with [SAML clients](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#saml-clients) to provide the sort of bridging you describe.  Other solutions likely exist as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution that I know of that allows you to change protocols "on the fly".

You would have to roll your own and you would very quickly be going down the rabbit hole e.g token signing, mapping OIDC attributes to SAML ones (there's not a one to one relationship), signing out etc.

The easiest way is to use an external IDP that allows both OIDC and SAML and this will give you SSO across your applications.

If you have to use your current IDP then federate this with one that can deliver both protocols.

There are a number around e.g. Azure AD, Auth0, Okta etc.